# How to move the model along the Z axis in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realitykit

I've already loaded the model and I want the model to move along the `z` axis.

My code is here:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ARContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: [0, 0, -1])
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        arView.cameraMode = .ar                  
        
        let model = try! Entity.loadModel(named: "box.usdz")
        
        anchor.addChild(model)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        
        model.move(by: SIMD3<Float>(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.5), 
             duration: 0, 
           relativeTo: nil)
        
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```

However, it showed error **No exact matches in call to instance method 'move'**. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using ChatGPT answers . You used `by` parameter instead of `to` parameter in [move(to:relativeTo:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/entity/move(to:relativeto:)-556u9) instance method. Also type is wrong and parameters are not in their places. The content of your `move(...)` method must be the following:

```
  model.move(to: Transform(translation: .init(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.5)),
     relativeTo: nil,
       duration: 0.5,
 timingFunction: .easeInOut)
```

Comment: Why when I changed `z: -0.5` to `z: 0.5`, the model still moved like `z: -0.5` ? I think it should be moved in the opposite direction.

Comment: `z = -0.5` is your scene's North direction, right? Do you take into account the location of the anchor?

Comment: In the scene, y is the North direction.

Comment: +Y must be `up` direction, -Y must be `gravity` direction, -Z is `North`, +Z is `South`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/worldalignment/gravity